# How can I get around the length limit for org-mode files? (disabling linum-mode for orgs only)

Tags: memory, emacs, org-mode

Org-mode starts to choke around 4000 lines with a really simple outline (I've seen crashes as well as generally slow behavior). This is depressingly short. What can I do to alleviate this? Is there a plugin, project, hack, or update? (I'm using version 7.9.2.)

#### edit

So since it seems to be the fault of `linum-mode`, what's the simplest way to keep `global-linum-mode` on but disable it for org files?

Comment: Have you tried disabling line numbering `(linum-mode -1)` if that is active?  Also, known to cause slow downs is coloring whitespace for every single space with `whitespace-style`.

Comment: So in this case `linum-mode` was the issue; is it storing all the lines in some buffer?

Comment: No, it's a `post-command-hook` thing-a-ma-bob that involves counting lines from point-min to point-max ever time you breathe, plus adding overlays.  There is a setting to not update so often (e.g., `linum-delay` and `linum-schedule`), but I haven't played around with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding something like this in your configuration file:

```
(defun my/turn-off-linum-mode ()
  (linum-mode -1))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my/turn-off-linum-mode)
```

Comment: Ohh, it was -1 to turn off! I went with `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook linum-mode -1)`. Thanks.

Comment: I think your solution is not equivalent to mine: with yours, linum-mode is called without argument; -1 is interpreted as a non-nil `APPEND` argument to `add-hook`, meaning the function will be added to the end of the list. Calling `linum-mode` without argument toggles the state of the mode, which should deactivate it in your case (since it is activated by default using `global-linum-mode`), but it is not robust.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I wasn't sure why you wrote the solution that way, but it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

How about this version?

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda() (linum-mode -1)))
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail as to how this would work.